# DataTableReader.NextResult() causes false results from HasRows()

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a generic exe that use to create files based on a SqlDataReader.  There could be more than one recordset within this reader.  There are also extended libs that can be added to run more complex data queries, but would return a SqlDataReader.  I recently had to change, because of the extended libs that run off the SqlDataReader can't write to SQL anymore to build it's table from multiple data sources.   So now those libs create a internal DataTableReader, which could have 1 or more recordsets, just currently they have only one.

My problem is, I found once I switched over to DataTableReaders within my generic EXE, that when I call .NextResult() to get the next recordset, then call if(reader.HasRows()) to verify if a recordset exists, it always returns true, even when there is only one recordset.

Is there something I have to do when creating the DataTableReader to ensure the HasRows returns the correct results?

I've tried two different ways when creating the DataTableReader.

```
1: dataTable.CreateDataReader();
2: new DataTableReader(new DataTable[] { dataTable });
```

Both cases still return true on HasRows after a .NextResult() method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use "HasRows" to check if next recordset exists. Verify what is returned by actual call to `DataTableReader.NextResult()`. If it's False then no next recordset exists.

Check out [basic sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) in MSDN docs.

Comment: Yea, I guess I was playing lazy with SqlDataReaders, because HasRows does return the expected results.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hello for me it's normal that HasRows return true because you actually have one record in your table. If you want to know if there is no more record in youe reader you should put your reading code in `while (yourReader.read())` then do you reading code in the while loop

Comment: That was already being done, this is after the fact.  Thanks though.